# how to get specific str in python using regular expression?

Tags: python, regex

I have a str like 
`rjg[]u[ur"fur[ufrng[]"gree`,

and i want to replace "[" and "]" between "" with #，the result is

`rjg[]u[ur"fur[ufrng[]"gree` => `rjg[]u[ur"fur#ufrng##"gree`,

how can i get this in python?

Comment: problem is regex doesn't nest.

Comment: What does "between" quotes mean here.  What should the outcome of `xx"["["xx` be?

Comment: no format like `xx"["["xx` , cause in my case, the "" will appear in pair

Answer (score 4):

One liner solution:

```
import re

text = 'rjg[]u[ur"fur[ufrng[]"gree'
text = re.sub(r'(")([^"]+)(")', lambda pat: pat.group(1)+pat.group(2).replace(']', '#').replace('[', '#')+pat.group(3), text)
print text
```

Output:

```
rjg[]u[ur"fur#ufrng##"gree
```

Answer (score 1):

I would try

```
L = data.split('"')
for i in range(1, len(L), 2):
    L[i] = re.sub(r'[\[\]]', '#', L[i])
result = '"'.join(L)
```

Comment: I would add that regex module alone is unable to perform that task (no nesting support)

Answer (score 0):

An option would be using [`str`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str) built-in functions [`split()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) and [`replace()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace) like below (**without regex**):

```
s = 'rjg[]u[ur"fur[ufrng[]"gree'
l = s.split('"')
new_string = '"'.join(w.replace('[', '#').replace(']', '#') for w in l[1:-1])
res = '"'.join((l[0], new_string, l[-1]))
```

**Output:**

```
>>> res
'rjg[]u[ur"fur#ufrng##"gree'
```

Answer (score 0):

A one liner without regular expression. Though your solution is very wonderful @jpnkls.

```
>>> text = 'rjg[]u[ur"fur[ufrng[]"gre[e]"abc[d"ef]"'
>>> '\"'.join([substr.replace('[', '#').replace(']', '#') if n % 2 == 1 else substr for n, substr in enumerate(text.split('\"')[:-1])]+[text.split('\"')[-1]])
rjg[]u[ur"fur#ufrng##"gre[e]"abc#d"ef]"
```

This still works for uneven numbers of quotes and a quote at the beginning or the end.